# dynamic IFRAME content - how to get the access to that IFRAME?

Tags: javascript

I'm loading a content dynamically to the `<iframe>`

```
<iframe style='border:none;' id='abc' src="http://localhost:39217/Home/GetContent/some_dynamic_code"></iframe>
```

after a success response, in that iframe is that content

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function onPageLoad() {
              if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                  var cont = document.getElementById("abc");
                  alert(cont);    
              }
          }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload='onPageLoad()'>
      <a target="_blank" href='http://lorem'>
        <img class='abc' style='max-width:300px; max-height: 38px;' alt='' src='/Images/image.png' />
      </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

That `iframe` will be using outside my site (by users), but I want to have the ability to change the `<img>` `src`. But, I need also to change the `width/height` of the `iframe`after I change the image. So, how can I get the access to that `iframe` using JS ? That code above `alerts` me `null`

Comment: You are setting a class and searching for an ID..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS interaction between iFrames and their parents is for what I know impossible or at least troublesome. I know there is somewhere a property `window.frames` and maybe even `frame.parent` but in general, JS interaction like that is impossible. I think you should consider another type of solution (like an ajaxcall maybe, if that could satisfy your needs).

Comment: notice that img has the abc class, but the iframe has the abc ID, I want to get the iframe object, not the img

Comment: @EricG: it seems like he wants to show a remote content in an iframe. In such case an ajax call is not an option (cross-domain ajax calls are not allowed)

Comment: I said "maybe", because it isnt specified that it will be crossdomain or not. I was precaustious there. I'd agree really..

Answer (score 2):

I made an example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/KRaWU/2/

I use jQuery to achieve that and I suggest you do the same.

```
// this will find a button within an iframe
var obj = $('iframe').contents().find('.actionButton').find('input[type="submit"]');
// this will change the value of the button, and you can see that the text is changed.
obj.attr('value', 'LOG ME IN');
```

You can analogically find an img and change its src.